# Gwt security widget level

Tags: security, gwt, web

I'm probably asking a newbee question but i'm wondering if there is a security issue to use roles to set the visibility of some field in a a Gwt panel (Smartgwt but doesn't change the problem).
I have securitty checking  server side on the main services restricted for some roles and besides I instaniate only the panels corresponding to the user granted access but in some case I need to reduce the data visible on some views for some roles.
If there is a security issue what will be the best workaround for such a request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot expect to hide data you send to a client with the user interface, since the user can always access the data via some other interface that you *didn't* create.  Don't use GWT to reduce data visibility - always do that on the server.  You only control the server, even if it seems like you control the client.

Comment: Thanks, it's a great help to my thought. This is  to my sense a problem with RIA where as you said 'it seems like you control the client'. So I caught: the only way to "filter" the visible data is to select the data send by the server depending on the role of the user. On the client side the job is only to hide the field which are irrelevant because thay don't have dat to expose anyway.